# Apache Iceberg: Is it possible to manually set snapshot time during historical load

Tags: apache-iceberg, data-lake

We have a number of datasets we would like to move to iceberg that already have a historical or audit component to them.  In each case we either capture changes in the same table or in an audit table (i.e. Hibernate Envers).  We're looking at Iceberg as a tool in a new data lake effort and would like to capture and maintain that history (and timestamps) as we load the data.  I'm curious if there is a way to do a "historical" load of data into the iceberg format where we maintain the original change dates/times.